# Qt::AA_SynthesizeMouseForUnhandledTouchEvents on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, windows-7, qt5

I created a simple widget which outputs the mouse and touch events it receives to `qDebug()` (excerpt):

```
// ...

MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent), acceptEvents(false)
{
    this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);
}

static QEvent::Type const mouseEventTypes[] = {
    QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick,
    QEvent::MouseButtonRelease,
    QEvent::MouseButtonPress,
    QEvent::MouseMove
};

static QEvent::Type const touchEventTypes[] = {
    QEvent::TouchBegin,
    QEvent::TouchUpdate,
    QEvent::TouchEnd
};

template<typename Container, typename Value>
bool contains(Container const & c, Value const & v)
{
    return std::find(std::begin(c), std::end(c), v) != std::end(c);
}

bool MyWidget::event(QEvent * e)
{
    auto type = e->type();
    if(contains(mouseEventTypes, type))
        qDebug() << "MouseEvent";
    else if(contains(touchEventTypes, type))
        qDebug() << "TouchEvent";
    else
        return QWidget::event(e);

    e->setAccepted(this->acceptEvents);
    return true;
}

// ...

const bool acceptEvents = true;
const bool synthesizeMouse = false;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    app.setAttribute(Qt::AA_SynthesizeMouseForUnhandledTouchEvents, synthesizeMouse);

    MainWindow gui; // contains a MyWidget as centralWidget
    gui.setAcceptEvents(acceptEvents);
    gui.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

However, no matter how I set `acceptEvents` and `synthesizeMouse`, I always receive both mouse and touch events when I use a multitouch monitor on my system (which is a Windows 7 system). Is there any way to *only* get touch events on Windows using Qt when the touch events are accepted?

Update:

The effectively undocumented [`nomousefromtouch` parameter](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/odysseus-qtbase/commit/94abcf98175d927f8e483c8f207c51034fd3b9fc) has no effect either, however with Qt 5.3, `QMouseEvent::source()` reports `Qt::MouseEventSynthesizedBySystem` for most (yes, most... in very rare cases a `Qt::MouseEventNotSynthesized` is reported for a mouse move) synthesized mouse events. This means I might be able to disambiguate the events myself (most of the time), however a nicer/easier/cleaner solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had no luck setting attributes as you mentioned.
However when I changed the method for setting attributes from `app.setAttribute()` to `QCoreApplication::setAttribute()` at the beginning of the application, things started to work out for me.

You should try that.